# Fat-Free with Cortex Models and REST

Tags: php, rest, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to use FatFree and Cortex plugin within my REST API. I seem to have some challenges, at first I was challenged with the namespaces, which I was trying to find how to solve that. And then once I set that up, it was giving issues with method get() already existed. I later tried to not use namespaces to see if that would help, but continued with errors.

I am hoping to get some clarification on how to setup Cortex + F3 + REST API and having auto mapping routes. What am I doing wrong on setting up the model for Cortex? Namespaces doesn't really matter, if I use them or not (personally). Just would like it to work.

My Autoloader is

```
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD','app/controllers/;app/models/');
```

Here is my file setup
[image]

Comment: What is the working directory of your process? I assume it is in `app/..` or `app/../public`? Your `AUTOLOAD` paths are relative to the working directory. I could imagine that it is possible to load `Contacts` (→ `app/controllers/Contacts.php`) but not `\App\Models\ContactsModel` (→ `app/models/App/Models/ContactModel` is invalid).

Comment: Hey @Rayne, yes, my working DIR is 'app'. And all my classes load fine through the `AUTOLOAD` but when it came to namespaces it got confusing. `$f3->set('BASE','/');
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD','app/controllers/;app/models/');` is what I have currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple issues here.

- don't mix different upper-case lower-case namings for files and folder or the autoload will not find it.. use file path App/Controllers/Contacts.php when your namespace is \App\Controllers\Contacts or name all files and folder in lower-case.. but don't mix them
- When you set your namespace at `\App\Controllers`, `\App\Models`, etc. your AUTOLOAD setting should only be `''` to use the project root. If you set AUTOLOAD to `app/`, then your namespace begins at this folder, so it's just `namespace Controllers`. Same for Models
- When you are within a namespace, you have to add a leading `\` to your namespace of other files, so within namespace `\App\Controllers` in you must use `new \App\Models\ContactsModel` .. if you only write `new App\Models\ContactsModel`, it'll look for a file at `app/controllers/app/models/contactsmodel.php`

I would suggest:

- change folder names to: `app/Models` and `app/Controller`, etc
- leave file names for classes the same as the class name so `class ContactsModel` -> `ContactsModel.php`
- set `AUTOLOAD` to `app/` only
- use namespaces like folders within app/, so ContactsModel -> `namespace Model;` and `Contacts` -> `namespace Controllers`

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications @ikkez, appreciate F3. I will keep churning through Cortex, thanks.